# Application Object defined error (1004)

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to create a method that creates a value in a certain column of the excel sheet. Keep running into the runtime error above on the Sheets.Cells.Value = Cint line. Any idea what could be the problem? Thanks!

```
For Each Cell In Sheets(tab_name).Range(cell_range)
    current_row = Cell.Row
    split_cells = Split(Cell.Value, ".")
    Sheets(tab_name).Cells(current_row, 58).Value = CInt(split_cells(0))
Next Cell
```

Comment: Does it have "." ?  Check the array split_cells first before using it

Comment: You should verify if cell is not empty

Comment: Maybe `split_cells = Split(Cell.Value & ".", ".")` ...? The `split_cells(0)` will still be correct if there is something to split and should work as a `vbnullstring` if not.

Comment: I can't replicate this with sample data. Note that the 1004 error won't be related to the `CInt` - that would either be a subscript error or a type mismatch. Set a breakpoint an test the values of `Sheets(tab_name).Cells(current_row, 58)` to see if it's a valid range.

Comment: I stepped through it and the cells(current_row, 58) is empty, but I want to change that empty value to a different value. Does it have to have a value there?

Answer (score 0):

The cell must be empty.  Split will return an array for any non-empty string.

[image]
Here is a simpler way to write it:

```
For Each Cell In Sheets(tab_name).Range(cell_range)

    With Cell.EntireRow
        If Cell <> "" Then 
            split_cells = Split(Cell.Value, ".")
           .Cells(1, 58).Value = CInt(split_cells(0))
        Else
           .Cells(1, 58).Value = 0
        End If

    End With
Next Cell
```

Comment: Yes the cell is empty, but I want to change that empty cell to the split_cells value. Is this not possible?

Comment: I had my code structured wrong.  Check my update.  The source cell is empty.  You can not split an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Would `INT(Cell.Value)` not suffice for what you are trying to do?